# Show / hide keyboard using LocalSoftwareKeyboardController without using TextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom composable that I would like to "attach" to a software keyboard, meaning I want input to be handled by the keyboard and the output rendered on my custom composable.

This custom composable is **not** a `TextField`. I have a `MutableState<String>` for the keyboard input and my custom composable correctly renders this state.

I have seen solutions in other frameworks/languages, like Flutter, where an invisible `TextField` is used to achieve this. But it seems like a hack - and I don't know if it's possible in Compose...

Note: I need to configure the keyboard using `KeyboardOptions` and `KeyboardActions`.

**Question: How can I configure the software keyboard to be shown when my custom composable is in focus and to be hidden when it is not in focus?**

Relevant APIs that I think are needed for the solution:

- `androidx.compose.ui.platform.SoftwareKeyboardController`
- `androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions`
- `androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions`
- `androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester`

Comment: In order for a keyboard to show, the target view/composable should interact with input service and have active `InputConnection` once it has gained focus. The hacky solution is mentioned is exactly because of this reason I stated above. They are focusing the hidden text field so the input connection starts and then transferring the input text as state to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It was not clear from my question that this is about a dialog but my solution was basically to:

1. Set DialogProperties attribute `decorFitsSystemWindows` to `false`
2. To set `Modifier.imePadding().fillMaxHeight()` on the Column that wraps everything including the TextField used to attach the keyboard